# jQuerynot working in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a click to toggle class function that isn't working for Firefox and IE 11 (works on Chrome). I'm using the toggleClass method to animate my hamburger menu, but the classes aren't being added.

The jQuery function before it (to generate the current year) works fine.

Any ideas? Nothing appears in the console for both browsers when I click on the button.

Here's my code.

jQuery

```
var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();

$("#year").text((new Date).getFullYear());

$(".contact").click(function() {
  $('.bar1').toggleClass("left");
  $('.bar2').toggleClass("right");
  $('.bar3').toggleClass("down");
  $('.close').toggleClass("closeUp");
  $('.contact-btns').toggleClass("contact-btns-reveal");
});
```

HTML Button

```
<button class="btn btn-lg hvr-bounce-to-right dropdown-toggle" 
data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
aria-expanded="false"><a href="#" class="contact">Get in Touch
     <div class="toggle">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
     </div>  
    </a>
</button>

<div class=" contact-btns">
   <a href="#">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox" title="Shoot me an email"></i>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt" title="Let's talk"></i>
   </a>
   <a href="#">
     <img src="img/In-White-54px-R.png" alt="Find me on Linkedin" title="Find me on LinkedIn">
   </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ok, i have to ask.  Why do you have an <a> inside a <button>?  Works for me (in ff) if you remove the button.

Comment: Not really sure. I wrapped the button in an <a> tag and that fixed it. Thank you

Comment: Dude dude dude, seriously.  Why do you feel the need for the <a> tag?

Comment: It's been a while since I've built a website and forgot you don't need an a tag in thise case.

Comment: Use a button or an a tag, no need to wrap one in the another

Comment: Heh, ok.  Just checking.  Your small change and 'it works' got me scared you were doing a band-aid without understanding what you actually *needed*.

Comment: Thank you both for the help!